# Divide block of asp.net mvc code into different file parts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have hundred lines of code asp.net in my view, It make me difficult to find what I need it. So do anyone have some idea to divide it into separate files? As I know, in php , have function include().

Comment: Resharper? Refactor into classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ASP.NET MVC [partial views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942822.aspx#id0070036).  These let you break down your view into separate reusable components, similar to user controls in ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: In addition what @Chris suggested, you can also use view templates to provide the base layout and then use partial views to fill in the gaps for each page.